# Reference or term for connected sage-on-the-stage?

Tags: reference-request, general-pedagogy

I heard that there is evidence that a "connected sage-on-the-stage" teaching style is at least as effective as guide-on-the-side / flipped classrooms. I have been unable to find significant references for "connected sage-on-the-stage", so I may have the term slightly wrong. Does anyone know a reference for this idea?

It is a variant of sage-on-the-stage that calls for heavy classroom interaction and participation but without radical change like flipping the classroom.

Comment: @TommiBrander the term originates from 
King, Alison, From Sage on the Stage to Guide on the Side. College Teaching, Vol. 41, No. 1 (Winter, 1993), pp. 30-35.

Comment: @MichaelE2 your reference 2014b is very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some references, with no particular claim of their significance:

- [Plett, Melani & Wilson, Denise & Bates, Rebecca & Allendoerfer, Cheryl & Carlson Jones, Diane & Floyd-Smith, Tamara & Veilleux, Nanette & Wasilewski, Caitlin. (2014). People Matter: The Role of Peers and Faculty in Students’ Academic Engagement. ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition, Conference Proceedings.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280572090_People_Matter_The_Role_of_Peers_and_Faculty_in_Students%27_Academic_Engagement)
- [Painter, Sarah (2014) "Modeling Student Engagement in the Classroom," Journal of Undergraduate Research at Minnesota State University, Mankato: Vol. 14 , Article 6.](http://cornerstone.lib.mnsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1050&context=jur)
- [King, Alison (1993) "From Sage on the Stage to Guide on the Side", College Teaching, Vol. 41, No. 1, 30-35](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/87567555.1993.9926781) [mistakenly given as [2010](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/87567555.1993.9926781) in my comment, 2010 being the date of online publication].

Comment: The first of these three references is a useful answer. The second mentions "connected sage on the stage" only in passing and the third not at all (unless I missed it).

Comment: The third is the source of the original phrase "sage-on-the-stage". The later "connected sage-on-the-stage" term is the one I am seeking references for.